# Temporal data grouping by date ranges SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[rx](
            [pat_id] [int] NOT NULL,
            [fill_Date] [date] NOT NULL,
            [script_End_Date]  AS (dateadd(day,[dayssup],[filldate])),
            [drug_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
            [days_Sup] [int] NOT NULL,
            [quantity] [float] NOT NULL,
            [drug_Class] [char](3) NOT  NULL,
            CHECK(fill_Date <=script_End_Date
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
            [clmid] ASC
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calendar](
            [cal_date] [date] NOT NULL,
            [julian_seq] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
--unsure if the above line is an acceptable way of adding a 'julianized date number', the data in this database ranges from 1-1-2007 to 12-31-2009
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
            [cal_date] ASC
)
```

I have my table of interest and a calendar table with the structures above.  I'm trying to find the max number of distinct drugs that a person is taking in a set number of families at a given time (overlapping dates) by the field drug_class.

I had success with help from the community here on a similar problem, but at the moment I'm doing something incorrect and getting wildly inaccurate results.  If possible, I would like for the result set returned to look like

```
create table DesiredResults
(pat_id int, min_overlap date, max_overlap date, drug_class char(3),drug_name varchar(50))
insert into Desired_Results(patid, minoverlap, maxoverlap, drug_class,drug_name)
values (1111,'2008-11-28', '2008-12-18','h3a','drug X')
      ,(1111,'2008-11-28','2008-12-18','h3a','drug Y')
```

this would mean that during the time frame above patient 111 was prescribed drug x and drug y.

My query is -

```
;with Overlaps (pat_id,cal_date,drug_class)
as
(
select
mdo.pat_id
,c1.cal_date
,mdo.drug_class
from
(
--this gives a table of all the scripts a person had within the classes restricted in the where rx.drug_class IN clause and their fill_date and script_end_dates
SELECT DISTINCT
 rx.pat_id
,rx.drug_class
,rx.drug_name
,rx.fill_date
,rx.script_end_date
FROM   rx
WHERE  rx.drug_class IN( 'h3a', 'h6h', 'h4b', 'h2f', 'h2s', 'j7c', 'h2e' )
--
) as mdo,Calendar as c1
where c1.cal_date between mdo.fill_date and mdo.script_end_date
group by mdo.pat_id,c1.cal_date,mdo.drug_class
having count(*) > 1--overlaps
)
,
Groupings(pat_id,cal_date,drug_class,grp_nbr)
as
(
select
o.pat_id
,o.cal_date
,o.drug_class
,c2.julian_seq

--julianized date
-row_number() over(partition by o.pat_id,o.drug_class order by o.cal_date) as grp_nbr
from Overlaps as o,calendar as c2
where c2.cal_date = o.cal_date
)
,x

as
(

--i think this is what's causing the problem

select pat_id,min(cal_date) as min_overlap,max(cal_date) as max_overlap,drug_class
from groupings
group by pat_id,grp_nbr,drug_class

)

select 
 x.pat_id
,x.min_overlap
,x.max_overlap
,y.drug_class
,y.drug_name
from x
inner join
(
select distinct
 rx.pat_id
,rx.drug_name
,rx.drug_class
,rx.fill_date
from rx
) as y on x.pat_id = y.pat_id and x.drug_class=y.drug_class
          and y.fill_date between x.min_overlap and x.max_overlap
order by datediff(day,min_overlap,max_overlap) desc
```

I'm looking for the span of days where the most drugs in a given class are being prescribed. However, right now this is giving me date ranges that are larger than any single `datediff(day,fill_date,script_end_date)`.

This is making the numbers artificially inflated because some of the overlap ranges are years long when at most they should be approximately the number of days that a doctor would write a script for.  If five drugs in the class 'h3a' were prescribed on the same day then I would catch that period of time as `pat_id`, `fill_date`, `end_date`, `h3a` repeated five times for each drug in that class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solves your problem.  This gives the dates where the maximum number of drugs are prescribed:

```
select c.cal_date
from (select c.cal_date, count(*) as NumDrugs,
             dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from Calendar c join
           rx
           on c.cal_date between rx.fill_date betwen rx.script_end_date and
              rx in IN( 'h3a', 'h6h', 'h4b', 'h2f', 'h2s', 'j7c', 'h2e' )
      group by c.cal_date
    ) crx
where seqnum = 1
```

It is much simpler than your query, so I'm wondering if I missed something.

If you need to turn this into periods, that is also possible, but the SQL is a bit more cumbersome.

Also, this SQL is untested so may have syntax errors.